Error in Hierarchical Multiple Factor Analysis (HMFA) with Mixed Data Types in R
I am trying to perform a Hierarchical Multiple Factor Analysis (HMFA) using the FactoMineR package in R. I have a dataset that is divided into four groups, each containing variables of different types (nominal and quantitative). I need to analyze these groups using HMFA, but I am encountering an error.
Here is a quick description of how my group are structured:
Group 1 (columns 1 to 9) : All logical variables that i considered as categorical in my analysis.
Group 2 (columns 10 to 63) : Mixture of 40 nominal (from 10 to column 51) and 12 quantitative variables (columns 52 to 63)
Group 3 (columns 64 to 113) : Mixture of 4 quantitative (from 64 to 67) and 46 nominal variables (from 68 to 113)
Group 4 (columns 114 to 135) : 1 quantitative and 21 nominal variables (from 114 to 135)
Each group represents a different aspect of my data, and the HMFA is expected to help me analyze the influence of these diverse variables within their respective groupings as well as their interactions across groups.
HMFA Setup:
I defined the groups and variable types as follows:
H <- list(
  9,    # Group 1
  54,   # Group 2
  50,   # Group 3
  22    # Group 4
)

types <- c(
  rep("n", 9),           # All nominal for Group 1
  rep("n", 41), rep("s", 13),  # Nominal and scaled for Group 2
  rep("s", 4), rep("n", 46),   # Scaled and nominal for Group 3
  rep("s", 1), rep("n", 21)    # Scaled and nominal for Group 4
)

res_hmfa <- HMFA(
  X = my_data,
  H = H,
  type = types,
  ncp = 10,
  graph = FALSE,
  axes = c(1, 2),
  name.group = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4")
)

I've also tried by replacing H with H2 :
H2 <- list(
  c(1:9),   # Group 1
  c(10:63),  # Group 2
  c(64:113),  # Group 3 
  c(114:135)   # Group 4 
)

But i still get the same error : "not convenient group definition" : Erreur dans MFA(X, group = H[[1]], type = type, graph = FALSE) :
not convenient group definition
4.
stop("not convenient group definition")
3.
MFA(X, group = H[[1]], type = type, graph = FALSE)
2.
hweight(X, H, type = type)
I've noticed that many examples of Hierarchical Multiple Factor Analysis (HMFA) incorporate nested group structures. However, my dataset does not fit into a nested framework, and I'm unsure how to properly configure HMFA for a flat group structure like mine.
If anyone has experience or examples of HMFA applied in scenarios with non-nested, distinct groupings, I would greatly appreciate any insights or sample code you could share. Understanding how to apply HMFA effectively in such contexts would be extremely helpful.
Thanks in advance!
